# How to disable header in createDrawerNavigation from Reac Navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

**Background**

While building a React Native application and using a `DrawerNavigator` from React Navigation I ended up needing to customize the header that comes with a `createDrawerNavigator`. I found that I can customize a `createStackNavigator` though.

**createStackNavigator**

1. Can hide the header
2. Can customize the header.

**createDrawerNavigator**

1. Can NOT hide the header
2. Can NOT customize the header.

**Question**

How do I hide or customize the header that automatically is added to my app when using the `createDrawerNavigator` from React Navigation?

**Example**

***createStackNavigator***

*I can hide the header that appears when using `createStackNavigator` like this,*

```
const Secure = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: {
      screen: drawer,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
```

***createDrawerNavigator***

When using `createDrawerNavigator` nothing I try works to hide or customize the header. I have also searched the documentation and can not find anything referencing how to deal with the header in React Native navigation Version 3 for `createDrawerNavigator`.

Comment: Like the answer below me said, just pass header: null in navigationOptions to all relevant components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This code will be help the header none for custom drawer component.**

```js
const customDrawerContentComponent = (props) => {
   Contact: { 
    screen: ContactScreen ,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
   }
}



const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
       header: null
    })
  }
}, {
  contentComponent: customDrawerContentComponent,
})
```

Comment: This does not work for me. When I add navigationOptions to createDrawerNavigator  and set header to null, I still see the header load in my app. This exact config works for stackNavigator but does not work on createDrawerNavigator.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer from Kazi said, you can pass **headerMode: null** to hide the header from the drawerNavigators and the stacknavigator. The problem with this is that you end up with no headers at all.

So if you want headers for specific screens, there's a **header** component on **react-native-elements** that you can add to each screen you want a header on.

Here's an example:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Header
    statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'light-content' }}
    barStyle="light-content"
    leftComponent={
      <SimpleIcon
        name="menu"
        color="#34495e"
        size={20}
      />
    }
    centerComponent={{ text: 'HOME', style: { color: '#34495e' } }}
    containerStyle={{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
    }}
  />
</React.Fragment>
```

In this example, I had to wrap it on React.Fragment tags because I put this part of the code in the beginning of the render method. I also added a title to the screen and the hamburguer button to open the drawer.

So, basically what I did is, hide the header on both stackNavigators and drawerNavigators then add the component to each of your screens that you do want a header on.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. My goal is not to hide both headers. My goal is to hide the drawerNavigator Header. I am able to pass in a custom header to the stack navigator that allows me to add icons on both sides. I can not customize or hide the header of the drawerNavigator. This means i have 2 headers. headerMode null and all the other popular choices I have seen online do not work for drawer.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation v6

`screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}`

Example minimal setup:

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

<AppNavigator.Navigator
            initialRouteName="SomeName"
            screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
```